# не работает внешний скрипт js

Tags: javascript, html, веб-программирование

внутри html документа скрипт работает[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а внешний скрипт не работает[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У вас порядок не правильный, tippy.js запускается раньше, чем сама tippy тянется с CDN, перенесите строчку вниз, как показал тут ( http://joxi.ru/MAj3vYzfx1o6dr )

Comment: спасибо большое

Answer (score 1):

Как ответил Вам в комментарии @ferrari, вы сначала загружаете скрипт в котором используете tippy, и только после этого загружаете саму библиотеку tippy. Просто загружайте tippy.js после загрузки cdn

Comment: работал спасибо